# Node.js - res.send() never sending message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

For some reason, no matter what I try, my response message is not getting sent. For a short while it was working, then I messed with some code and now it's broken. Anyone know the answer to my tricky little problem?

```
    exports.listBoth = function(req, res)
    {
        blah.find({name: req.params.name}).count().exec(function (err, count)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(count);
                if(count >= 1)
                {
                    blah.find({name: req.params.name}).exec(function (err, blah)
                        {
                            res.jsonp(blah);
                        }
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    res.send('No blah Found');
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Your code is missing the closing `};` for listBoth function. BTW, what value do you see when code reaches `console.log(count)`?

Comment: @xmikex83 hey, already resolved it....was missing the json object. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve the issue you have faced with, you need to change your response to send JSON object instead of mentioned string.

You may do something like:

```
res.send({message: 'No blah Found'});
```

or

```
res.status(404).send({success: false, error: {message: 'No blah Found'}});
```

etc.

So the main point is passing JSON object in order to get it sent correctly.

In some situation you may use `res.json()` to convert entity automatically, but it will not work correctly with strings.

Comment: PERFECT! I thought it would be much more complicated. Thank you!

Comment: And how do I retrieve this message on the frontend if i am using Angular?

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom error class like the below example, you could send error message natively with this code

```js
const err = new CustomError('Custom Error...');

...

res.send(err);
```

err's message included automatically

I searched for implementation of the Error class in 'core-js'

[image]

[https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/wrap-error-constructor-with-cause.js#:~:text=if%20(message%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20createNonEnumerableProperty(result%2C%20%27message%27%2C%20message)%3B](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/wrap-error-constructor-with-cause.js#:%7E:text=if%20(message%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20createNonEnumerableProperty(result%2C%20%27message%27%2C%20message)%3B)

So, if you want message should be displayed in console or delivered by JSON you should use the following code

```js
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor (message) {
    // super(message)
    super() // avoid message's non-enumerable property

    this.name = this.constructor.name
    this.message = message;

    // needed for CustomError instanceof Error => true
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);

    // Maintains proper stack trace for where our error was thrown (only available on V8)
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
    }
  }
}
```